# dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cryptsetup_2%3a2.3.5-1~bpo10+1_amd64.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/luksformat'

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, apt

Ubuntu 18.04:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

# uname -a
Linux z 5.4.0-90-generic #101~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 22 09:25:04 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat debian_version 
buster/sid
```

`# apt update`

Works fine.

`# apt upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cryptsetup-initramfs : Depends: cryptsetup (>= 2:2.3.5-1~bpo10+1)
                        Breaks: cryptsetup (< 2:2.0.3-1)
 cryptsetup-run : Depends:    cryptsetup (>= 2:2.1.0-6)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I run `apt --fix-broken install`...

```
# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cryptsetup
Suggested packages:
  keyutils
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cryptsetup
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.
102 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/225 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,192 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 422374 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cryptsetup_2%3a2.3.5-1~bpo10+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cryptsetup (2:2.3.5-1~bpo10+1) over (2:2.0.2-1ubuntu1.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cryptsetup_2%3a2.3.5-1~bpo10+1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/luksformat', which is also in package cryptsetup-bin 2:2.0.2-1ubuntu1.2
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cryptsetup_2%3a2.3.5-1~bpo10+1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`# apt policy`

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-y-ppa-manager,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Y PPA Manager,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-y-ppa-manager,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Y PPA Manager,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main armhf Packages
     release o=code stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=code stable,c=main,b=armhf
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main arm64 Packages
     release o=code stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=code stable,c=main,b=arm64
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=code stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=code stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main i386 Packages
     release o=TeamViewer GmbH,a=stable,l=TeamViewer,c=main,b=i386
     origin linux.teamviewer.com
 500 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=TeamViewer GmbH,a=stable,l=TeamViewer,c=main,b=amd64
     origin linux.teamviewer.com
 500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
     release o=Sublime Text,a=apt/stable,l=Sublime Text APT Repository,c=
     origin download.sublimetext.com
 500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main i386 Packages
     release v=1,o=packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack,a=jessie,n=jessie,l=slack,c=main,b=i386
     origin packagecloud.io
 500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1,o=packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack,a=jessie,n=jessie,l=slack,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packagecloud.io
 500 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release o=. xenial,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=. xenial,c=main,b=amd64
     origin updates.signal.org
 500 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/retroshare/xUbuntu_18.04  Packages
     release o=obs://build.opensuse.org/network:retroshare/xUbuntu_18.04,n=xUbuntu_18.04,l=network:retroshare,c=
     origin download.opensuse.org
 500 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable/main all Packages
     release o=proton-gitlab,n=stable,c=main,b=all
     origin repo.protonvpn.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/polychromatic/stable/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-polychromatic-stable,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Stable,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/polychromatic/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-polychromatic-stable,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openrazer/stable/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-openrazer-stable,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Stable Branch,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openrazer/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-openrazer-stable,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Stable Branch,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/hardware:/razer/xUbuntu_18.04  Packages
     release o=obs://build.opensuse.org/hardware:razer/xUbuntu_18.04,n=xUbuntu_18.04,l=hardware:razer,c=
     origin download.opensuse.org
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-graphics-drivers,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Proprietary GPU Drivers,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-graphics-drivers,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Proprietary GPU Drivers,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google LLC,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google LLC,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-gezakovacs,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=UNetbootin PPA,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-gezakovacs,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=UNetbootin PPA,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     release o=Docker,a=bionic,l=Docker CE,c=stable,b=amd64
     origin download.docker.com
 500 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian unstable/main all Packages
     release o=proton-gitlab,n=unstable,c=main,b=all
     origin repo.protonvpn.com
 100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free i386 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=buster-backports,n=buster-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=non-free,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=buster-backports,n=buster-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib i386 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=buster-backports,n=buster-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=contrib,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=buster-backports,n=buster-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=buster-backports,n=buster-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=buster-backports,n=buster-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Canonical,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Partner archive,c=partner,b=i386
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Canonical,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Partner archive,c=partner,b=amd64
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

How to fix?

Comment: Are you aware that you’re trying to install a Debian Buster backports package? That’s not going to work well on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt: No, I was not aware of this.  I was just trying to do an update/upgrade.  What do you recommend?